# Independence of shifted random variables

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose that

$(X,Y_{1},...,Y_{N})$

is a collection of mutually independent random variables. Is it true that

$(X-Y_{1}, X-Y_{2},...,X-Y_{N})$

are mutually independent? I can't seem to find any references on this.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have a reference for this result? Or at least a keyword I can search for myself?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork This is not true.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not true. Let $(X,Y_1,\dots,Y_N)$ be i.i.d. Bernoulli$(1/2)$, so each is equal to either $0$ or $1$ with equal probability. I will let $P(A,B,C)$ refer to $P(A\cap B\cap C)$, for short.
$$
P(X-Y_1=1,X-Y_2=1)=P(X=1,Y_1=0,Y_2=0)=1/8,
$$
but
\begin{align}
P(X-Y_1=1)P(X-Y_2=1)
&=P(X=1,Y_1=0)P(X=1,Y_2=0)
\\&=(1/4)(1/4)
\\&=1/16.
\end{align}

---

**Edit:** Even more simply, if $Y_1,Y_2,\dots,Y_N$ are all zero with probability $1$, then $(X-Y_1,\dots,X-Y_N)=(X,X,\dots,X)$ is not independent, because $X$ is not independent of itself (as long as $X$ is non-constant).

Comment: I think you can now delete the first part. The first example that came to mind was $Y_i=0$ for all $i$. +1 from me.